# Configuring MantisBT to send emails using GMail

Tags: notifications, bug-tracking, mantis, bug-tracker

I am new to Mantis bug tracker and I want to enable the email notification after registering for a new account.

Well, I installed the MantisBT correctly without any problem on my local computer, I already changed the admin's password and removed the admin folder in the directory. After this I signed up for a new account, there was a confirmation message flashed saying that I need to verify my registration via email. My problem here is that no verification message was sent to my email. According to one of the tutorials I found, I need to configure first my **config_inc.php**. After the installation, the initial content of my config_inc.php was

```
<?php
$g_hostname      = 'localhost';
$g_db_username   = '<myUser>';
$g_db_password   = '<myPass>';
$g_database_name = 'bugtracker';
$g_db_type       = 'mysql';
?>
```

So I changed it to.
**I am using my gmail account here*

```
<?php
$g_hostname      = 'localhost';
$g_db_username   = '<myUser>';
$g_db_password   = '<myPass>';
$g_database_name = 'bugtracker';
$g_db_type       = 'mysql';

$g_allow_signup             = ON;
$g_allow_anonymous_login    = OFF;
$g_anonymous_account        = '';

$g_phpMailer_method     = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP; 
$g_smtp_host            = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_smtp_username        = '<myUser@gmail.com>';
$g_smtp_password        = '<myPass>';
$g_administrator_email  = '<myUser@gmail.com>';
$g_webmaster_email      = '<myUser@gmail.com>';
$g_from_name            = 'Mantis Bug Tracker';
$g_from_email           = '<myUser@gmail.com>';
$g_return_path_email    = '<myUser@gmail.com>';
$g_email_receive_own    = OFF;
$g_email_send_using_cronjob = OFF;

$g_allow_file_upload    = ON;
$g_file_upload_method   = DATABASE;
$g_absolute_path_default_upload_folder = '';
$g_max_file_size        = 5000000;
$g_preview_attachments_inline_max_size = 256 * 1024;
$g_allowed_files        = '';
$g_disallowed_files     = '';

$g_window_title         = 'MantisBT';
$g_logo_image           = 'images/mantis_logo.gif';
$g_favicon_image        = 'images/favicon.ico';

$g_show_realname = OFF;
$g_show_user_realname_threshold = NOBODY;

$g_default_home_page = 'my_view_page.php';
?>
```

I overwrite my **config_inc.php** with this one and then register for a new account. After submitting the information, an error occured saying:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method SMTP::getError() in < myDirectory >\mantis\library\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1910.

And now I'm stucked, please help me with this, I need to setup my email notification. I was just creating accounts but I cannot use them because I need to verify it.

Please let me know if I need to modify some of the related files and what are the steps.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of Mantis are you using?

Comment: I think you should report a bug at http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/bug_report_page.php

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to a [posting on the MantisBT forums](http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10331), these are working settings for GMail:

```
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_smtp_username = 'username@gmail.com';
$g_smtp_password = 'yourpassword';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_smtp_port = 465;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This one works for me, but I removed the ":465" in smtp_host but it works! I don't know if there is bug, but I think already tried this one (or maybe there was a little difference). Anyway, thanks for this!

Comment: I used WAMP, which need extra steps as pointed out by mantis forum post (http://fluffy.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15398): - If you are using WAMP server then make sure you have enabled the Apache >>Apache modules>>ssl_module AND PHP>>Php extensions>>php_openssl

Answer (score 3):

Something to add about GMail. These settings are correct but GMail has instituted some new security that will still prevent email from being sent from Mantis or any other mailer using the SMTP connector.

In order to do this with GMail, you must ["Allow less secure apps to access accounts"](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en). In GMail admin, there is a setting to allow users to control access from "less secure apps," which must be turned on, and then the user account used to send mail must turn on access from "less secure apps." The link above provides the information on how to configure this.

The frustrating thing is everything will appear to work fine but no emails are sent. There is no error indication from the SMTP server. However, the user account used to send mail may receive an email from GMail indicating someone is trying to access the account. I spent hours trying to track this down.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone still faces issue or error while configuration add log level so that you can drill down the problem further. Below settings worked for me. Detailed explanation is written [here](http://letzdotesting.com/email-configuration-mantisbt/)

```
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_smtp_port = '465';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_smtp_username = 'letzdotesting@gmail.com';
$g_smtp_password = 'xxxxx';
$g_administrator_email = 'letzdotesting@gmail.com';
$g_webmaster_email = 'letzdotesting@gmail.com';
$g_from_email = 'letzdotesting@gmail.com';
$g_return_path_email = 'letzdotesting@gmail.com';
$g_default_timezone = 'UTC';
$g_log_level = LOG_EMAIL | LOG_EMAIL_RECIPIENT;
$g_log_destination = 'file:C:\mantisbt.log';
```

Comment: Warning: replace 'smart' apostrophes with plain apostrophes.

Answer (score 2):

```
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_smtp_username        = 'username';   // without @gmail.com
$g_smtp_password        = 'password';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_smtp_port = 465;
```

it Works for me

Answer (score 2):

**2017 update (MantisBT 2.3.0) Please follow the steps below:**

**[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv0OW.png)] IF YOU'RE USING DOCKER**

Access the docker instance running the command below:

```
docker exec -it {docker-id} bash
```

**[2] INSIDE MANTISBT SERVER**

if you dont have any editor:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# apt-get install vim
```

create a log file:

```
# touch /var/log/mantisbt.log
# cd /var/log/
# chmod 777 mantisbt.log
```

**[3] EDITING MANTISBT CONFIGURATION**

```
# vim /var/www/html/config/config_inc.php
```

add the following content to the file opened in the earlier step:

```
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_administrator_email = 'your-admin-email@gmail.com';
$g_webmaster_email = 'your-webmaster-email@gmail.com';
$g_return_path_email = 'your-return-email@gmail.com';
$g_from_email = 'your-from-email@gmail.com';

$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_smtp_port = 465;
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_smtp_username = 'username';
$g_smtp_password = 'password';

$g_log_level = LOG_EMAIL | LOG_EMAIL_RECIPIENT;
$g_log_destination = 'file:/var/log/mantisbt.log';

$g_validate_email = OFF;
```

**[4] EDITING GMAIL CONFIGURATION**

You need to do this in order to allow MantisBT authentication:

1. Access the following URL:

   https://myaccount.google.com
2. Navigate to the Sign-in & Security menu-item under menu-tree.
3. Check the "**Allow less secure apps**" option and set equals to true

Image:
[image: enter image description here]]

You're good to go!
Tested and running with these configurations. =]

Comment: what about smtp ? in my docker image it's missing

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by updating ca certificates. 
I am using Xampp, with PHP 7.2 on Windows sever 2012.

Although the below link provides you with the details, I mention the relavent part too:

> ### Updating CA certificates
>
> Updating CA certificates To update your CA certificates, make sure
>   your operating system is fully up to date - CA certs are usually
>   updated via OS updates. Alternatively, you can [download](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) the latest CA
>   cert file from curl, install it somewhere accessible (for example
>   /etc/ssl/cacert.pem) and point at it from the openssl.cafile and
>   curl.cainfo directives in your php.ini file (this location will vary
>   according to your OS and PHP config; where you need to put it is
>   beyond the scope of PHPMailer!):
>
> ```
> openssl.cafile = /etc/ssl/cacert.pem 
> curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
> ```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#updating-ca-certificates