# Email not sending in mantisbt while creating user

Tags: php, smtp, smarty, mantis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configuring MantisBT to send emails using GMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356904/configuring-mantisbt-to-send-emails-using-gmail)

Following is my email (smtp) configuration in **config_inc.php** for sending mail in mantis bt :

```
# --- Email Configuration ---
$g_phpMailer_method = "PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP"; # or PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP, PHPMAILER_METHOD_SENDMAIL
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';   # used with PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP
$g_smtp_port = 587;
$g_smtp_username = 'demo@gmail.com';  # used with PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP
$g_smtp_password = 'xxxxxx';     # used with PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP
$g_administrator_email = 'demo@gmail.com';
$g_webmaster_email = 'demo@gmail.com';
$g_from_name = 'xpticket Bug Tracker';
$g_from_email = 'demo@gmail.com'; # the "From: " field in emails
$g_return_path_email = 'demo@gmail.com'; # the return address for bounced mail
$g_email_receive_own = "ON";
$g_email_send_using_cronjob = "ON";
$g_use_bcc = 'demo@gmail.com';
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
$g_default_email_on_priority = 1;
$g_default_email_on_status = 1;
# --- Attachments / File Uploads ---
```

But when I am trying to create user its creating user in database. Also getting password in database in hashed format. But its not sending any mail, also not showing any error. Its redirecting me previous page without any error. Same is happening while resetting password.

Any Help....

Thanks