# Mantis bug tracker don't sent the reset password email?

Tags: php, xampp, mantis

In mantis bugs tracker, When I create new user and press Reset Password button, It can't send the reset password email to user !!!! why ??

Or, is there any configuration to make it sent the reset password email?

This is my email configuration:

```
$g_hostname = 'localhost';
$g_db_type = 'mysql';
$g_database_name = 'bugtracker';
$g_db_username = 'root';
$g_db_password = 'root';
$g_allow_signup    = ON;  
$g_enable_email_notification = ON; 
$g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP;
$g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_send_reset_password=ON;
$g_smtp_connection_mode = 'tls';
$g_smtp_port = 587;
$g_from_email= 'Waseelac@gmail.com';
$g_smtp_username = 'Waseelac@gmail.com'; //replace it with your gmail address
$g_smtp_password = '******'; //replace it with your gmail password
$g_administrator_email = 'mohammad.hasan@waseela-net.com';
```

Comment: Does it send emails at all?

Comment: The mantis can't send any email, nothing

Comment: Then I suggest to amend your question to reflect that and post your email configuration.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356904/configuring-mantisbt-to-send-emails-using-gmail

Answer (score 0):

It's because for some weeks google requires you to use SSL. So change connection_mode to ssl and port to 465.